# user meta cut off when accessing via rest api

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

I have a custom user meta which is filled with an array containing ids and data.

When I access it within my custom REST API endpoint it gets cut off.

```php
function app_api_favorites()
{
    $favorite_ids = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'learndash_favorites', true);
    return $favorite_ids;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('my-endpoint/v2', 'favorites', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'app_api_favorites'
    ]);
}
```

Result:

```json
{
    "5": {
        "7": {
            "207": {
                "self": true,
                "audios": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do basically the same thing in an external file like this:

```php
require_once('wp-load.php');
$favorite_ids = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'learndash_favorites', true);
var_dump($favorite_ids);
```

Then I get the expected result like this:

```json
array(2) {
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    [7]=>
    array(4) {
      [207]=>
      array(2) {
        ["self"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["audios"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [594]=>
      array(1) {
        ["self"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      [349]=>
      array(2) {
        ["self"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["audios"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [598]=>
      array(1) {
        ["self"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
    [184]=>
    array(3) {
      [1311]=>
      array(2) {
        ["audios"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["self"]=>
        bool(true)
      }
      [1312]=>
      array(1) {
        ["self"]=>
        bool(true)
      }
      [1310]=>
      array(1) {
        ["self"]=>
        bool(true)
      }
    }
    [182]=>
    array(2) {
      [1325]=>
      array(1) {
        ["self"]=>
        bool(true)
      }
      [182]=>
      array(1) {
        ["audios"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(1) "4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [1799]=>
  array(4) {
    [13542]=>
    array(1) {
      [13592]=>
      array(1) {
        ["audios"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [12984]=>
    array(1) {
      [13085]=>
      array(1) {
        ["audios"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
      }
    }
    [13248]=>
    array(1) {
      [13259]=>
      array(1) {
        ["audios"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
      }
    }
    [13168]=>
    array(1) {
      [13223]=>
      array(1) {
        ["audios"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the full data inside the REST API without it beeing cut off?

Comment: Are you sending credentials with the request you are making to the REST API? Otherwise `get_current_user_id()` will only return 0.

Comment: @CBroe yes I'm using JWT auth

Comment: And you verified that works as intended? If you just make your function return the result of `get_current_user_id()`, you get the correct user ID returned?

Comment: @CBroe just tested it to be 100 % sure and it shows me the correct ID.

Comment: get_user_meta calls get_metadata, which in turn calls get_metadata_raw, and in there, the filter `get_{$meta_type}_metadata` gets applied - so it could be that you are outside of the context here, where the learndash plugin has added its own function to that hook, to append the data, or something similar like that.

Comment: @CBroe you showed me the way. I accessed the database directly to see where the problem first occurs and the user ID was filled in but I was logged in with the wrong user. Typical layer 8 error.